# Why is my Bootstrap 5 navbar not displaying the drop down menu on smaller screens?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to develop a bootstrap 5 theme for the latest WordPress. I am using  Navwalker from here: https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker. My bootstrap Navbar does not dropdown on smaller screens.

Is it not working because I am using Bootstrap 5 and not bootstrap 4?

Here is my code from my header.php file:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-controls="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Toggle navigation', 'your-theme-slug' ); ?>">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'container'         => 'div',
            'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
        ) );
        ?>
    </div>

</nav>
```

Here is my code from my functions.php file:

```
function register_navwalker(){
require_once get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_navwalker' );

/*Navigation Menus*/
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'bootstrap' ),
    'secondary' => __( 'Secondary Menu', 'bootstrap' )
) );
```

This is my error:

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'register_navwalker' not found or invalid function name in C:\Users\apiro\Local Sites\wordpressbootstraptheme\app\public\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 292

Call Stack

```
Time    Memory  Function    Location
```

1   0.0003  413560  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0

2   0.0006  413832  require( 'C:\Users\apiro\Local Sites\wordpressbootstraptheme\app\public\wp-blog-header.php' )   ...\index.php:17

3   0.0006  414376  require_once( 'C:\Users\apiro\Local Sites\wordpressbootstraptheme\app\public\wp-load.php' ) ...\wp-blog-header.php:13

4   0.0007  414816  require_once( 'C:\Users\apiro\Local Sites\wordpressbootstraptheme\app\public\wp-config.php' )   ...\wp-load.php:37

5   0.0007  419496  require_once( 'C:\Users\apiro\Local Sites\wordpressbootstraptheme\app\public\wp-settings.php' ) ...\wp-config.php:79

6   0.0325  2624792 do_action( )    ...\wp-settings.php:538

7   0.0325  2625168 WP_Hook->do_action( )   ...\plugin.php:484

8   0.0325  2625168 WP_Hook->apply_filters( )   ...\class-wp-hook.php:316

Answer (score 0):

In nav walker class file, change all "data-" atrribute to "data-bs-"

Example: change "data-toggle" to "data-bs-toggle"

I fink have only one line to change ;)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two distinct issues here.

1. There is a section in the GitHub page you link to that states that the data attributes need to be amended for Bootstrap 5:

> Bootstrap 5 uses namespaced data attributes. All data attributes now
> include bs as an infix. The new attributes work just like the old
> ones.

So as already stated, any attribute that starts `data-` will need to be changed to `data-bs-` instead.

This is actually created as a pull requested along with some other modifications for usage with Bootstrap 5: https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/pull/531

2. The PHP warning could be made simpler by just including the required file from your functions.php file like so: `include_once get_template_directory().'/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';` and removing the wrapping function and hook into `after_setup_theme`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your code and setup, so let's tackle them step-by-step:

**1. Bootstrap 5 Data Attributes:** With the introduction of Bootstrap 5, the data attributes for toggling the collapse component have changed.

Replace:

**html**

```
data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
```

**With:**

```
data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
```

This is an important change because in Bootstrap 5, all data attributes now have the bs- prefix.

**2. Bootstrap 5 Navwalker:** If you're using Bootstrap 5, ensure that your version of `WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker` supports Bootstrap 5. At the time of my last training data, the navwalker you're using was designed for Bootstrap 4. You may need to look for a different navwalker or adjust the current one to fit Bootstrap 5 changes.

**3. Function Not Found Error:** The error you're seeing is because the `register_navwalker` function is not found or not available at the time of the `after_setup_theme` action. Make sure that the `register_navwalker` function is actually being defined before the `add_action` call. Ensure there's no conditional logic or any other issues preventing the function from being defined.

The path you're using in the `require_once` call seems correct, but double-check the file name and path to ensure the file is present and the path is correct.

**php**

```
require_once get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';
```

**4. Debugging:** It's always a good practice to enable debugging in WordPress when you're working on theme or plugin development. Add these lines to your `wp-config.php`:

**php**

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

This will enable debugging, log all errors to a file, and prevent them from being displayed to the user. You can then inspect the `wp-content/debug.log` file for any error messages.

By addressing the Bootstrap 5 data attributes and ensuring that your `WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker` class file is correctly included, you should get closer to resolving the dropdown issue. Remember that any other JavaScript or CSS conflict can also interfere with Bootstrap's functionality, so always check for console errors and try to rule out conflicts when debugging.